# Access variables from a child component in parent component's callback function in React and render the returned value in parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How does the following situation work:

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => <Text>{item.key}</Text>}
/>
```

Here, `FlatList` receives a callback function which can access an object that contains `item` variable(as can be seen) which is coming from the child component `FlatList`. It somehow is able to give the object(containing `item`) to the callback and still render the item using `renderItem` prop that is passed to it.

I am trying to achieve something similar here: [my sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/4wr55vxmvx)

But I am facing this error which says that React child cannot be a function. The point is completely valid I agree, but I am unable to think of something else as to how to achieve it. Maybe I am missing some simple concept here.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: as per your sandbox, I dont see you are passing any arguments to your `getSummary` and `getDetails`. I think you should pass arguments to them to return the component. That should fix your error.

Comment: Its a class function above @Pranay

Comment: you need to pass arguments when its being called in order to get any return value.  A class function doesn't need binding but you are using arguments rather than class variables. Hence, you are not able get the value as when you component is rendering `summary` or `details` , its finding the reference of the function rather the actual return value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per your sandbox, you need to pass arguments when its being called in order to get any return value. In a class function, you don't need to pass values if you are using class level variables, but in your case you are using arguments to execute the function that is why you need to pass arguments to it. That is why, you are not able get the value as when your component is rendering `summary` or `details` , its finding the reference of the function rather the actual return value.

I have made changes to your [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/0pzy7870nw) to pass dummy values, you can replace it as per your requirements.

Comment: You have manually passed values into the functions in your edit of sandbox. That was not the requirement. I wanted the child to pass the (key, value) pair by utilizing the data component. Just like it is in FlatList component in react native. You just pass the the data in the data prop and get an object containing the item in renderItem prop. That's what I want to know, how did they do that.

Comment: can you add the code of `ExpantionPanelList` ? In that component you might wanna iterate the list and render the each item in your data array.

Comment: I'm unable to open the sandbox.

Comment: Actually, I didn't consider the structure of the data object that I was passing. Your sandbox pointed it out to me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should update your code with return statement.

```
<FlatList
    data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
    renderItem={({item}) => {
        return <Text>{item.key}</Text>;
    }}
/>
```

Comment: I am using it without the curly braces you have enclosed around the return statement, so I can omit the return keyword.

Comment: @MdBalal as I know <FlatList> has to have return statement. Can you try the following code and reinform me so I can try to find another solution.

Comment: Dear @tron, this code is copy pasted exactly from RN official docs. Please see https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist

Answer (score -1):

Just simply use `(` and `)` instead of `{ }`. This will return your component.

```
<FlatList
  data={[{key: 'a'}, {key: 'b'}]}
  renderItem={({item}) => (
       <Text>{item.key}</Text>
     )   
  }
/>
```

Comment: That is not the question!